# What is the difference between find-grep and grep-find?

Tags: emacs

What is the difference between `find-grep` and `grep-find` in Emacs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `M-x describe-function` (or `C-h f` with default keybindings) to answer this question, here's the output for `find-grep`:

```
find-grep is an alias for `grep-find' in `progmodes/grep.el'.
(find-grep COMMAND-ARGS)
...
```

Answer (score 6):

They seem the same.  See [the manual](http://www.impernix.org/Manuals/emacs/Grep-Searching.html)